# PHP preg_match Ë doesn't work

Tags: php, preg-match

I have the following preg_match but i can't get the Ë from the string.

```
$title = 'This is blablabla BRAZILIË';
preg_match_all('/\b([A-Z]+)\b/', $title, $matches);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => BRAZILI
    )
```

I want:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => BRAZILIË
    )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use unicode property for uppercase letter `\p{Lu}` and don't forget `u` modifier:

```
$title = 'This is blablabla BRAZILIË';
preg_match_all('/\b(\p{Lu}+)\b/u', $title, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

According to comment, this a way to lowercase multibyte character see [mb_strtolower](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.mb-strtolower.php):

```
$title = 'This is blablabla BRAZILIË';
preg_match_all('/\b(\p{Lu}+)\b/u', $title, $matches);
$res = ucfirst(mb_strtolower($matches[0][0]));
echo "$res\n";
```

**Output:**

```
Brazilië
```

Comment: That works, but after that BRAZILIË has to be Brazilië. Whit ucfirst i am getting BraziliË

Comment: That did it! Thnx mate!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use unicode matching. Try this:

```
preg_match_all("/\b([A-Z\x{c0}-\x{ff}]+)\b/u", $title, $matches);
```

Depending on your use cases, you may want to extend the characters by looking at this table: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/

Comment: Thnx, this works, only after that strtolower and ucfirst returns BraziliË, how can i fix that to Brazilië?

Comment: In fact, what are the words that you intend to match?

Comment: CAPITAL words to Capital words, so the first letter ucfirst()

Comment: I see. Use different range then: `\x{c0}-\x{ff}`

Comment: I used this one and worked in combination with your solution http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php#91805 THNX!!!